# Fourier FFT frequencies

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am using FFT (`Fourier`) on a dataset that contains the temperature along a rod `1m` long. The data is  sampled with a spacing of `0.01m`, so I have 100 measurements in total.

This gives me a sampling rate of `100 1/m`. Now, when I call `Fourier` I get out a list with `100` numbers in frequency-space, where the first corresponds to `0`-frequency.

Say I shift the data so the `0`-frequency will be in the center. I am unsure of what the largest and smallest wavevector is.

Is it simply `-50` (smallest) and `+49` (largest)? Thereby implying that the smallest perturbation my FFT can resolve is `1/0.02 = 50`, i.e., `0.02m`?

Comment: If you FFT a complex sinusoid with a whole number of cycles over your data set,   you can easily find the correspondence between frequency and bin number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frequencies $f$ returned by the FFT (`Fourier`) are

$f={0,d,2d,...,(N/2)d,(-N/2+1)d,(-N/2+2)d,-2d,-d}$,

where $N$ is the number of points in the input series, and the frequency increment is $d=1/T$ where $T$ is the period of the input series. In your case, the "period" $T=1$ meter, so $d=1 m^{-1}$. The special frequency $(N/2) d$ is the Nyquist, or folding, frequency, and is the highest frequency representable by the FFT. There is one zero frequency, one Nyquist frequency, and $(N-2)/2$ positive/negative pairs of other frequencies.

```
f = d * Join[Range[0, n/2], -n/2 + Range[1, n/2 - 1]]
```

Shifting the data so that the zero frequency is in the centre requires (for even $N$)

```
RotateRight[f,Floor[Length[f]/2-1]]
```

where `f` is the original list of frequencies. Thus, the list of frequencies to associate with the 100 numbers returned by `Fourier` is, after shifting:

{-49, -48, -47, ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., 48, 49, 50}